# Install4j Mac OS X installer throws NullPointerException

Tags: install4j

Looking through the `installation.log` I found my Mac OS X installer (built with install4j 6.1) is throwing a `NullPointerException` when running the `InstallFilesAction`. Apparently it's trying to use `AppleScript` but it can't find the engine:

```
[ERROR] com.install4j.runtime.beans.actions.InstallFilesAction [ID 6]: 
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.install4j.runtime.installer.helper.AppleScriptHelper.initEngine(AppleScriptHelper.java:30)
        at com.install4j.runtime.installer.helper.AppleScriptHelper.executeWithReturnValue(AppleScriptHelper.java:42)
        at com.install4j.runtime.installer.helper.AppleScriptHelper.getRecords(AppleScriptHelper.java:21)
        at com.install4j.runtime.installer.platform.macos.MacProcessHelper.addGuiProcesses(MacProcessHelper.java:104)
        at com.install4j.runtime.installer.platform.macos.MacProcessHelper.getRunningProcesses(MacProcessHelper.java:81)
        at com.install4j.runtime.installer.helper.RunningProcessChecker$RunningProcessThread.run(RunningProcessChecker.java:329)
        javax.script.ScriptException: AppleScript engine not found
javax.script.ScriptException: AppleScript engine not found
        at com.install4j.runtime.installer.helper.AppleScriptHelper.executeWithReturnValue(AppleScriptHelper.java:44)
        at com.install4j.runtime.installer.helper.AppleScriptHelper.getRecords(AppleScriptHelper.java:21)
        at com.install4j.runtime.installer.platform.macos.MacProcessHelper.addGuiProcesses(MacProcessHelper.java:104)
        at com.install4j.runtime.installer.platform.macos.MacProcessHelper.getRunningProcesses(MacProcessHelper.java:81)
        at com.install4j.runtime.installer.helper.RunningProcessChecker$RunningProcessThread.run(RunningProcessChecker.java:329)
```

Is there a way to fix this?

EDIT: I also reproduced this on an installer built using `6.0.4`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is a bug in the JRE that occurs on some machines. This exception means that some processes cannot be detected but it does not impact the installer otherwise.

Comment: Hi Ingo, thanks for getting back to me so quickly. Could you provide a link to a Java bug report?

Comment: I researched the problem again in the meantime, and I might have a fix. Can you contact me at support@ej-technologies.com so I can send you a build?

Comment: Hi Ingo, this problem occurs also in 6.1.1 - Are you sure that `java.lang.NullPointerException at com.install4j.runtime.installer.helper.AppleScriptHelper.initEngine(AppleScriptHelper.java:34)` is not a bug in install4j? I would expect some other exception with some meaningful message if there is some problem with detecting processes, as you wrote, not just NPE.

Comment: The source of the problem is that the AppleScript engine cannot be found in the ScriptEngineManager in the JRE.